# Can I shutdown specific route in runtime in the express server?

Tags: node.js, express, http

I have an example

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

In the runtime (for example in 10 sec), I want to stop handling my `/` endpoint, so when I will make a request, the response would be like `Cannot GET /`

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a flag that can be set based on when you want to keep preventing the route from providing the data. Instead of showing `Cannot GET /`, you should send the status code `503` status code i.e service unavailable.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  
  if (flag) {
    res.status(503).send('Service Unavailable');
  } else { 
    res.send('hello world');
  }
});
```

This could be great if you want to make it for a single route. When you want to control many routes, you can create middleware and use flag similar to the above one.